# Что нужно сделать, чтобы загрузить код для страницы www.mysite.ru/about?

Tags: html

У меня есть сайт www.mysite.ru. Если мне нужно загрузить код главной страницы, то файл с кодом я называю "index.html" и загружаю на сервер. А что нужно сделать, чтобы загрузить код для страницы www.mysite.ru/about?

Comment: Для mysite/about.html надо about.html, туда же, в корень сервера. А чтобы убрать расширение .html (но при этом сохранить Content-Type, чтобы браузер понимал верно), для этого есть .htaccess

Comment: Зависит от вебсервера и его конфигурации. Укажите их в вопросе.

Comment: @D-side как выяснилось, есть независимое от сервера решение...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> что нужно сделать, чтобы загрузить код для страницы www.mysite.ru/about?

создать каталог `about` (в корне сайта), а в нём — файл `index.html`.

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо большое!